# Canvas Drawing Application Wont Work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on this little drawing application type thing, but it won't work in Firefox. It works fine in chrome though. Here's the javascript, then I just have a regular old canvas element in HTML. Any help is appreciated!

```
/* FOR THE DRAWING APPLICATION */
/* =========================== */

var canvasMouse, contextMouse;

var started = false;
var x, y;

function initMouse() {

    // Get the drawing canvas
    canvasMouse = document.getElementById('drawing');
    contextMouse = canvasMouse.getContext('2d');

    // Add some event listeners so we can figure out what's happening
    // and run a few functions when they are executed.
    canvasMouse.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemovement, false);
    canvasMouse.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseclick, false);
    canvasMouse.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseunclick, false);

}

function mouseclick() {
    // When the mouse is clicked. Change started to true and move
    // the initial position to the position of the mouse
    contextMouse.beginPath();
    contextMouse.moveTo(x, y);
    started = true;

}
function mousemovement(e) {

    // Get moust position
    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;

    // If started is true, then draw a line
    if(started) {

        contextMouse.lineTo(x, y);
        contextMouse.stroke();

    }

}

function mouseunclick() {
    // Change started to false when the user unclicks the mouse
    if(started) {
        started = false;    
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The canvas element is somewhat new and finicky to get right across different browsers. What exactly is it that doesn't work?

Comment: well nothing works. The drawing doesn't work. It's supposed to be a sort of simple drawing application but it won't draw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offsetX` and `offsetY` are not supported in firefox (see [compatibility table here](http://www.reloco.com.ar/mozilla/compat.html)). Instead you need to use `layerX` and `layerY`.

The following will work in firefox (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr33F/3/)):

```
/* FOR THE DRAWING APPLICATION */
/* =========================== */

var canvasMouse, contextMouse;

var started = false;
var x, y;

function initMouse() {

    // Get the drawing canvas
    canvasMouse = document.getElementById('drawing');
    contextMouse = canvasMouse.getContext('2d');

    // Add some event listeners so we can figure out what's happening
    // and run a few functions when they are executed.
    canvasMouse.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemovement, false);
    canvasMouse.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseclick, false);
    canvasMouse.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseunclick, false);

}

function mouseclick(e) {
    // When the mouse is clicked. Change started to true and move
    // the initial position to the position of the mouse

    // Get moust position
    x = e.layerX;
    y = e.layerY;

    console.log("coords", x, y);

    contextMouse.beginPath();
    contextMouse.moveTo(x, y);
    started = true;

}
function mousemovement(e) {

    // Get mouset position
    x = e.layerX;
    y = e.layerY;

    console.log("coords", x, y);

    // If started is true, then draw a line
    if(started) {               
        contextMouse.lineTo(x, y);
        contextMouse.stroke();

    }

}

function mouseunclick() {
    // Change started to false when the user unclicks the mouse
    if(started) {
        started = false;    
    }

}

initMouse();
```

If you want to avoid browser specific conditional code and / or your canvas element is offset within the DOM hierarchy (read the limitations of layerX and layerY in the compatibility table linked to above), there may be an argument for using jQuery and its [`position()` method](http://api.jquery.com/position/).